# Lost name of tabs in gnome-terminal

Tags: 14.04, command-line, gnome-terminal

After trying to installing one of the themes I lost names of tabs
[image]

I reset settings in terminal, dconf, reinstall gnome-terminal but no luck. Theme was reset but tabs not come back. Also when I'm switching to vim I see name of edited file at the tab title. What am I missing? I'm using ubuntu 14.04 btw.

**UPDATE:**
Problem was in my .bashrc file after replacing it to default file from GuestSession everything came back.

Comment: Does this also happen in the guest session?

Comment: @Fabby Thanks a lot! It helped me figure out that problem was in my .bashrc file.

Comment: It is considered polite on this site to allow the person that helped you point you in the right direction to have a go at the answer before answering yourself.  :P  ;-)  Please also read my comment below the answer.  :-)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Problem was in my .bashrc file after replacing it to default file from GuestSession everything came back.

Comment: Could you please elaborate on the exact problem in the `.bashrc` file and the lines you changed so the next person around can use your solution as well??? ;-)